# Building a Web Application Using EJB, JPA, and JavaServer Faces using Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I downloaded and installed JDeveloper 11.1.2.3.0 (I don't have licence. I just want to do demo app using ADF and I am not using it for commercial purposes)

Then I did the following Oracle tutorial (Building a Web Application Using EJB, JPA, and JavaServer Faces):
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_51/jdtut_11r2_51_2.html

At step 3: Run and test the page, I get the following on JDeveloper Log:

```
<ViewHandlerImpl> <_checkTimestamp> Apache Trinidad is running with time-stamp checking enabled. This should not be used in a production environment. See the org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.CHECK_FILE_MODIFICATION property in WEB-INF/web.xml

<11.01.2013 18:25:26 ALMT> <Notice> <EclipseLink> <BEA-2005000> <2013-01-11 18:25:26.552--ServerSession(14553247)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073> 
<11.01.2013 18:25:26 ALMT> <Notice> <EclipseLink> <BEA-2005000> <2013-01-11 18:25:26.557--ServerSession(14553247)--Server: 10.3.5.0> 
<MessageFactory> <getMessage> 
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUSearchBindingCustomizer.getViewCriteria(JUSearchBindingCustomizer.java:1980)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlSearchBinding$QueryDescriptorImpl.getFilterCriteria(FacesCtrlSearchBinding.java:1325)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.table.BaseColumnRenderer._getFilterCriteria(BaseColumnRenderer.java:1871)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.table.BaseColumnRenderer._renderFilterField(BaseColumnRenderer.java:1755)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.table.BaseColumnRenderer.renderColumnFilterCell(BaseColumnRenderer.java:1206)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.table.BaseColumnRenderer.encodeAll(BaseColumnRenderer.java:163)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1452)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:511)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:923)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1681)
...
```

here is my web.xml (org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.CHECK_FILE_MODIFICATION part)

```
  <context-param>
    <description>If this parameter is true, there will be an automatic check of the modification date of your JSPs, and saved state will be discarded when JSP's change. It will also automatically check if your skinning css files have changed without you having to restart the server. This makes development easier, but adds overhead. For this reason this parameter should be set to false when your application is deployed.</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.CHECK_FILE_MODIFICATION</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

The value is false. I tried to switch to true, but still it is giving me the same error.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the wrong message.
The problem is this - java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUSearchBindingCustomizer.getViewCriteria(JUSearchBindingCustomizer.java:1980)

Not exactly sure what the issue is, it might help if you clarify at which stage of the tutorial you started getting this error.

Comment: I finished 1st page of that tutorial and half way on the 2nd page. The stage is called "Step 3 Run and Test the Page" - it is the first time you need to compile that app.

Comment: I didn't plug in ADF essentials into the project. I just downloaded JDeveloper and started doing that tutorial.